# If $a, b$ are in group and $ab$ has finite order $n$, why does $ba$ have order $n$ as well?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> If $a, b$ are in group and $ab$ has finite order $n$, why does $ba$ have order $n$ as well?

Since $(ab)^n=e$, I get $(b)(ab)^n(a)= ba$. This means that $(ba)^{n+1}=ba$, and $(ba)^n=e$.  But, I don't see how this follows if the group is not abelian.

How does the left side become $(ba)^{n+1}$ without being given that group is abelian?

Comment: Hint: conjugate

Comment: You can break that into steps:
$$(ab)^n=e$$
Then you multiply *on the left* by $b$:
$$b(ab)^n=b$$
Then you multiply *on the right* by $a$:
$$b(ab)^n a = ba.$$
You're not using that it's abelian in your proof. If you're careful about orders, you see that everything does, indeed, work out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ba=a^{-1}(ab)a$$

Conjugate elements.

Answer (score 1):

$ab$ and $ba$ have the same order, since they are conjugate elements:
$$ b(ab)b^{-1} = ba, \tag{1} $$
giving:
$$ \left(b(ab)b^{-1}\right)^k = b(ab)^k b^{-1} = (ba)^{k} \tag{2}$$
from which $o(ab)=o(ba)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for example if $(ab)^{2}=1$, then:

$$
(ba)^{3}=b(abab)a=ba\rightarrow (ba)^{2}=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the group to be abelian to show that $b (ab)^n a = (ba)^{n + 1}$.  Just write out the $a$'s and $b$'s on both sides to see that they're the same (try it for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ for example).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Cyclic permutation of products arise by *conjugation* $\ x\mapsto a^{-1} x a,\ $ e.g.

$$  bcd\cdots za\, =\, a^{-1}(abcd\cdots z) a$$

Conjugation is an isomorphism so preserves all "group-theoretic" properties, which includes the order of an element $\,g.\,$ Indeed, the order of $\,g\,$ is the order (cardinality) of the cyclic group generated by $\,g.\,$ But an isomorphic image of a group has the same order (cardinality).